# Rails 3 restful route problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

The following link works in my app:

```
<%= link_to "invitation", :controller => :invitations, :action => :index %>
```

To follow restful conventions i changed the link to:

```
<%= link_to "invitation", index_invitation_path %>
```

The error that i get is:

```
undefined local variable or method `index_invitation_path'
```

Rake routes yields:

```
invitations GET    /invitations(.:format)          {:controller=>"invitations", :action=>"index"}
```

The page name is index.html.erb. The model is invitation.rb. The controller is invitation_controller.rb. Routes has resources :invitations. What am i missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the routing correct:

```
resources :invitations
```

Then the correct helper for the index action (with the url /invitations.html) is

```
invitations_path
```

You can see more information by running rake routes. It will display text like the following:

```
             lists GET    /lists(.:format)
           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"lists"}
                   POST   /lists(.:format)
           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"lists"}
          new_list GET    /lists/new(.:format)
           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"lists"}
         edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)
           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"lists"}
              list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)
           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lists"}
                   PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)
           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"lists"}
                   DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)
           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"lists"}
              root        /(.:format)
           {:controller=>"lists", :action=>"index"}
```

The above was from a route of my own (for a model called List). The route helper method is shown immediately before the HTTP method. You have to remember to append the _path to each helper method. For example the helper methods I could use are:

```
list_path(list)
edit_list_path(list)
new_list_path
lists_path
```

Comment: i tried this... i must have left off the plural "s" on "invitations_path". Thanks. This did it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a route in your routes.rb file that defines a mapping to the invitations controller and the index action.

Typically this is created with a resources call

```
resources :invitations
```

Which creates several default routes, which you can see by running rake routes.

For single resources, you can also define it using a match call

```
match "invitations/:id" => "invitations#index", :as => index_invitation
```

The rails site has a great resource on routing that provides all the details: [Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

**Update:** Based on your updated question, your route includes an *invitaions* (notice the trailing 's') route - nothing with index or invitation. The index_ prefix is generated by the `resources` call when it creates the default routes for :invitations.

It looks like you've defined a custom `get` mapping for an invitation. While this may technically work, if you're aim is to support restful routes, use the `resources` method. And have a read of the Routing guide from rails it's very easy to follow and quite detailed.

Answer (score 0):

type **rake routes** in your console and look at listing of available routes. Seems to be there is no such route **index_invitation_path**? maybe it named differently

Comment: results of rake routes is added to question above. The reason i didn't include it is because i thought that if the first link worked, there had to be a route. Anyway... there it is above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "invitations_controller.rb" to contain InvitationsController.  Plural.

Comment: Jeez, I was just trying to help, and I turned out I was in fact correct! (see accepted answer)

Comment: Used my mouse for +1 good and not evil. Your is a worthy (and correct) answer for sure.

Comment: This is not correct. The name of the contents of the invitations_controller class has nothing to do with the routing in this case.

Comment: While your statement is correct, it is not an answer to the question. The fact that the `index_invitation_path` does not exist, has nothing to do with the controller-name, that would generate a totally different error.